# How to implement a conditional custom Json Converter hide a property

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-6.0, system.text.json, jsonconverter

I have a REST API in .Net that returns the following object:

```
public class MyDto 
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Age {get; set;}
  public string ContactNumber {get; set;}
}
```

I want to implement a custom JSON Converter that I can add as an attribute. When the object is serialized for the response, based on a value in an HTTP header, I want to exclude a specific property.

For example, if I add an attribute like this:

```
public class MyDto 
    {
      public string Name {get; set;}
      [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
      public int Age {get; set;}
      public string ContactNumber {get; set;}
    }
```

The response, when a particular header is set, should be:

```
{
 "Name":"Name",
 "ContactNumber":"1234567"
}
```

Comment: Might be simplest to have separate DTOs, and return those accordingly based on the header.

Comment: Make Age nullable and simply don't fill the property if you don't won't it to be returned. Thats a logic i wouldn't want to hide in an attribute anyways. If you don't want too see that null property in the json add an `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]` attribute then.

Comment: @Ralf this is just an example, but in my case it could be null for both cases.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay correct, but in my cases I have to implement 10-15 Dtos, and them need to implement automapper for all of them, so it is going to be hard to maintain

Comment: Yes. Because this is a hard-to-maintain requirement. Although,  I think I remember faintly a method, where you would have an accompanying property "ShouldSerializeXYZ" ... I'll try to find a resource about that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an other approach, since a converter doesn't have access to the `HttpContext`.

Starting from `System.Text.Json` version 7.0.0 you can customize a JSON contract.
This [version 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/7.0.0) can be used from within a `NET6` application.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts):

> The System.Text.Json library constructs a JSON contract for each .NET type, which defines how the type should be serialized and deserialized.

One [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) describes what you want to achieve:

> **Modification**: Conditionally serialize a property
> **How to achieve**: Modify the `JsonPropertyInfo.ShouldSerialize` predicate for the property.

---

Define a custom attribute that acts as a marker to target the properties that should be conditionally excluded.

```
public class ConditionallyExcludedAttribute : Attribute
{ }

public class MyDto 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [ConditionallyExcluded]    
    public int Age { get; set; }
    
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Set up a custom `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` that returns `false` for `ShouldSerialize` for the properties on your DTO models that have been marked with your custom attribute.

```
public sealed class CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var typeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);

        if (type.IsClass)
        {
            var propertiesToExclude = typeInfo.Properties.Where(o =>
                o.AttributeProvider?.GetCustomAttributes(false)?.Any(o => o is ConditionallyExcludedAttribute) ?? false
                ).ToList();

            propertiesToExclude.ForEach(o => o.ShouldSerialize = (_, _) => false);

            // Or remove the property.
            // propertiesToExclude.ForEach(o => typeInfo.Properties.Remove(o));
        }

        return typeInfo;
    }
}
```

Define a custom `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter` that uses custom `JsonSerializerOptions` with this `CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver` installed.

This custom formatter must only be applied when that expected HTTP header is present - see the `CanWriteResult` override.

```
public class CustomJsonOutputFormatter : SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter
{
    public CustomJsonOutputFormatter()
        : base(new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            TypeInfoResolver = new CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver()
            // Other settings go here
        })
    { }

    public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        var myHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["MyHeader"].ToString();
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myHeader);
    }
}
```

Register this custom formatter in `program.cs`.
Make sure that this `CustomJsonOutputFormatter` is at the top in the list of output formatters, at least before the default formatter, otherwise it doesn't get the chance to decide whether to take action (via `CanWriteResult`).

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    o => o.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new CustomJsonOutputFormatter())
    );
```

When that specific HTTP header has a value the custom JSON serialization will take effect, otherwise the regular one.

You can make all this more configurable and relying less on hard coded values, but that would make this question and answer to broad.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer, but this doesn't work if your endpoint returns IActionResult. It work perfectly if I return raw object.

[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecastIAction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();

    return Ok(result);
}

Comment: @Ash What do you mean with "this doesn't work"? The code snippet in above comment should have `public IActionResult Get()` instead of `public async Task<IActionResult> Get()` since the implementation in that same snippet does not do any async work.

Comment: If I return my object as an IActionResult (ex, public async Task<IActionResult> Get()), it does not hide the property with custom attribute, But If I return the raw object (Ex.  public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()), it hide the property. 

When we use IActionResult. we return Ok(myobject) -> OkObjectResult. maybe that overwrites the CustomJsonOutputFormatter

Comment: @Ash When you use `public async Task<IActionResult> Get())` and not having an async call await'ing a method, you should see the `CS1998` warning, `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls ...`

Comment: yeah I got that. But even with public IActionResult Get(), it doesn't work for me

https://github.com/asprna/DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolverPOC

Comment: @Ash I tried your repo and could reproduce. I've updated my answer about the part how to register the `CustomJsonOutputFormatter`; use `o.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new CustomJsonOutputFormatter()`. Can't explain the behaviour difference between your and my side. Please try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for time, it is working now. maybe it is due to the .Net version. I'm using .Net 6